# How to get newline on every iteration in jq

Tags: json, bash, newline, jq, output-formatting

I have the following file

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Arthur",
    "age": "21"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Richard",
    "age": "32"
  }
]
```

To display login and id together, I am using the following command

```
$ jq '.[] | .name' test
"Arthur"
"Richard"
```

But when I put it in a shell script and try to assign it to a variable then the whole output is displayed on a single line like below

```
#!/bin/bash

names=$(jq '.[] | .name' test)
echo $names

$ ./script.sh
"Arthur" "Richard"
```

I want to break at every iteration similar to how it works on the command line.

Comment: Post the code how you tried to store in a variable

Comment: I have edited my question and added the script as well

Comment: As an aside: the reason for single-line output is that you didn't double-quote `$names` in `echo $names`, which made the shell apply word splitting. Try `echo "$names"`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Couple of *issues* in the information you have provided. The `jq` filter `.[] | .login, .id` will not produce the output as you claimed on `jq-1.5`. For your original `JSON`

```
{  
   "login":"dmaxfield",
   "id":7449977
}
{  
   "login":"stackfield",
   "id":2342323
}
```

It will produce four lines of output as,

```
jq -r '.login, .id' < json
dmaxfield
7449977
stackfield
2342323
```

If you are interested in storing them side by side, you need to do variable interpolation as

```
jq -r '"\(.login), \(.id)"' < json
dmaxfield, 7449977
stackfield, 2342323
```

And if you feel your output stored in a variable is not working. It is probably because of lack of double-quotes when you tried to print the variable in the shell.

```
jqOutput=$(jq -r '"\(.login), \(.id)"' < json)
printf "%s\n" "$jqOutput"
dmaxfield, 7449977
stackfield, 2342323
```

This way the embedded new lines in the command output are *not* swallowed by the shell.

---

For you updated `JSON` (totally new one compared to old one), all you need to do is

```
jqOutput=$(jq -r '.[] | .name' < json)
printf "%s\n" "$jqOutput"
Arthur
Richard
```

Comment: @user3198755: Answer updated to your updated `JSON`. Thanks and happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

In case the .login or .id contains embedded spaces or other characters that might cause problems, a more robust approach is to ensure each JSON value is on a separate line.  Consider, for example:

```
jq -c .login,.id input.json | while read login ; do read id; echo login="$login" and id="$id" ; done
login="dmaxfield" and id=7449977
login="stackfield" and id=2342323
```